# Converting scales

Tags: calculus

Lets say I have a list of values like this [8,10,16,24,27,16]

I want to retrieve a value based on index. If I would use index=2 in this scenario i would want to get the value of 10. If i use an index=3.5 I could calculate a value based on the list, it would give me 20, midway between 16 and 24.

But all that is based on the scale beeing 1-6 (beacuse it is six values in the list). What if the index is based on a "diffrent scale" lets say 1-5, How could I calculate this in order to get a value?

I've tried i*6/5, but that would cause the index of 1 to be 1.2 which is not what I want. I want 1=1 and 5=6 so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear transformation from $x \in [a,b]$ to $y \in [c,d]$ is $$y=\frac{d-c}{b-a}(x-a)+c$$
For your example of $[1,5]$ to $[1,6]$ this gives
$$y=\frac 54(x-1)+1$$
The fraction rescales the length of the intervals and the subtraction of $a$ and addition of $c$ deal with the starting value.  You can simplify this to $y=\frac 54x-\frac 14$ but I left it the other way to see where the terms come from.